# How can I give indentation to string of code snippet in react-code-blocks?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-codemirror

I am using "react-code-blocks" package from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-code-blocks), In that I am trying to give indentation to code of string, Which I want to pass in "react-code-blocks".

String Which i was passing

code:

```
interface Shape {
          double getArea();
          default String getDescription() {
              return "This is a shape with an area of " + getArea();
          }
      }
```

And It Show as,

`

Now, **Question Is how can I give indentation or format this string of code snippet.**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. You should be using indent string of code. You can use any online beautifier or prettier for this purpose